# Gap beneath UINavigationController toolbar when in UITabBarController

Tags: layout, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I Have a UINavigationController inside of a UITabBarController.  I have the tabbar on my UITabBarController hidden.  When I show the bottom toolbar of my UINavigationController, it doesn't appear on the bottom of the screen.  Instead there is a 49 point gap beneath it.  If I don't put the NavigationController inside of a TabBarController, there is no issue, but I need to put it inside of a TabBar.